# Creating directory's in php

Tags: php

I have the following code to create directories:

```
mkdir(trim($_POST['property_builder']));
mkdir(trim($_POST['property_builder']."/".$_POST['property_city']));
mkdir(trim($_POST['property_builder']."/".$_POST['property_city'].""."/".$_POST['property_location']));
mkdir(trim($_POST['property_builder']."/".$_POST['property_city'].""."/".$_POST['property_location'].""."/".$_POST['property_type']));  
mkdir(trim($_POST['property_builder']."/".$_POST['property_city'].""."/".$_POST['property_location'].""."/".$_POST['property_type']."/".'Images-'.$_POST['property_name']));    
mkdir(trim($_POST['property_builder']."/".$_POST['property_city'].""."/".$_POST['property_location'].""."/".$_POST['property_type']."/".'Images-'.$_POST['property_name']."/".'Floor-Plan-'.$_POST['property_name']));
```

All the Post variables are set and the code is running fine:

But, I have a situation:

Imagine  `$_POST['property_builder'] = "Auriga"` and for the first time it creates and continues build the subfolder structure.

Again there is a new project of Auriga... I want it to park under, already created folder (Auriga) and not trigger an error!!

Comment: A simple `file_exists()` check?

Comment: [You really should check the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php), particularly the notes on the `recursive` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after:https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

just one line is what you need:

```
mkdir(
trim($_POST['property_builder']."/".$_POST['property_city'].""."/".$_POST['property_location'].""."/".$_POST['property_type']."/".'Images-'.$_POST['property_name']."/".'Floor-Plan-'.$_POST['property_name']),
null,
true
);
```

the `true` stands for recursive which will do all the work

Comment: This was the most accurate answer.. Any way I am showing an error. Still. But the job is done.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Use file_exists to check :**

```
 if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
      mkdir('path/to/directory');
    }
```